# C++ warning: suggest parentheses around arithmetic in operand of |

Tags: c++, warnings, parentheses

I have a code like

```
A = B|C|D|E;
```

Throwing the warning "suggest parentheses around arithmetic in operand of |"

Expecting that expression needs high priority paranthesis for operators, tried the following ways:

```
A=(B|C)|(D|E);
```

one more as :

```
A=(((B|C)|D)|E);
```

Still the same warning persists.

Please help me in resolving this.

Thanks,
Sujatha

**B, C,D are enums and E is an integer.**

Comment: which compiler are you using?

Comment: Your example compiles without warning with GCC.

Comment: What are B C D and E, exactly?

Comment: @Programmer: Run your source file through `gcc -E` and look at the output. Are you *absolutely* certain that the compiler's interpretations of A, B, C, D, and E are what you think they are?

Comment: @Programmer: can you post the exact compiler options you're using?  (I also can't seem to get this warning with `gcc-4.3` with `-Wall -Wextra`)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have some arithmetic operator in your expression that isn't really simply B, or that isn't really simply C, etc.  The compiler is suggesting that you parenthesize whichever expression so that readers will see that you wrote what you meant.  If you don't parenthesize, everyone has to remember exactly what the priorities are, and they have to figure out if you remembered when you wrote it.

Try this:  (B)|(C)|(D)|(E).

Comment: B, C, D are enums and E is an integer

Comment: I think you'd better do what greyfade suggested, run your source file through gcc -E.  One of your enums might accidentally be a macro that you didn't know about.

Answer (score 2):

This is a weird warning.  You only really need to pay attention to precedence when you're using different operators and those operators have different precedences.  For instance, in arithmetic multiplication has higher precedence than addition.

But in this case you're using only one operator multiple times. Bitwise or is associative and commutative (`(A | B) | C == A | (B | C)` and `A | B == B | A`) so there's really no reason for the warning.